# Radio with checkbox behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

A simple question for angular

I want to create a radio button that acts as checkbox
i have this code

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        {{ dataItem | json }}

        <br /><br />

        <input type="radio"
               id="isHuman_{{$id}}"
               name="RecDem"
               ng-value="TrueVal"
               ng-model="dataItem.IsHuman" />
        <label for="isHuman_{{$id}}">Human</label><br />

         <input type="radio"
               name="RecDem"
               id="isAlien_{{$id}}"
               ng-value="TrueVal"
               ng-model="dataItem.IsAlien" />
        <label for="isAlien_{{$id}}">Alien</label><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

and this JS

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.dataItem = {
        IsHuman : false,
        IsAlien : false
    };

   $scope.TrueVal = true;
   $scope.FalseVal = false;
}]);
```

but when i change the state of the radio, at first, it acts as normal but after second click, there is no event triggered

maybe i just miss something in **ng-value="{ if (true) then TrueVal else FalseVal }"**

any help would be appreciated..

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0701k7ke/4/

TIA

Comment: Ae you looking this http://jsfiddle.net/0701k7ke/7/ ?

Comment: ^ that simple hack.. lol.. its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use `ng-checked` property instead of `ng-model` property as `ng-checked` property allows to use to check/uncheck radio buttons (similar to behavior of checkbox). And use `ng-click` property for setting the object.

So your **HTML** should be:

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        {{ dataItem | json }}

        <br /><br />

        <input type="radio"
               id="isHuman_{{$id}}"
               name="RecDem"
               ng-checked='dataItem.IsHuman'
               ng-click="dataItem.IsAlien = false;dataItem.IsHuman=!dataItem.IsHuman;"
        />
        <label for="isHuman_{{$id}}">Human</label><br />

         <input type="radio"
               name="RecDem"
               id="isAlien_{{$id}}"
               ng-checked='dataItem.IsAlien'
               ng-click="dataItem.IsHuman = false;dataItem.IsAlien=!dataItem.IsAlien;"
        />
        <label for="isAlien_{{$id}}">Alien</label><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

And your **controller** should be:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.dataItem = {
        IsHuman : false,
        IsAlien : false
    };        
}]);
```

Comment: maybe i'll just do it like this.. Thanks man.. i thought there is something like **ng-value="{ if (true) then TrueVal else FalseVal }"**

Comment: Pleasure to help. Happy Coding :)